# Laravel how to use BelongsToMany

Tags: laravel, join, has-and-belongs-to-many, eloquent

I am confuse to use belongstomany in laravel.
following is my code.

users.php

```
public function guser()
{
    return $this-
>belongsToMany(User::class,'reportings','user_id','reporting');
}
```

SQL TABLEs

REPORTING TABLE:

```
 ID          USER_ID             REPORTING 
 ==========================================
 1            92                   95,96
```

USER TABLE:

```
 ID          NAME
 ================
 92          Sanjay
 95          Ankur
 96          Parkar
```

result:

```
Name                 Reporting Person
======================================
Sanjay                Ankur
```

**result expected:**

```
Name                 Reporting Person
======================================
Sanjay                Ankur & Parkar
```

can you guys please help me to get expected result.

Comment: how do you store these multiple values(95,96) in your table?

Comment: $inp = Input::get('multireporting');
            $values = implode(",",$inp);

               for ($i = 0; $i < count($inp); $i++) {
                $news = new Reporting();
                $news->user_id = $user->id;
                $news->reporting = $values;
                $news->save();
}

Answer (score -1):

I believe belongsToMany requires a pivot table(would also be best practice to store single values in your database) so why not go that route?

Anyway you could do something like this:

User model:

```
public function reportings()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Reporting::class);
}
```

And this function for grabbing the users:

```
public function getReporters()
{
    //This is just to grab a user, you will probably do it dynamically
    $user = User::find(92);

    $reportings = $user->reportings()->get();

    foreach ($reportings as $reporter) {
        $arr = explode(',', $reporter->reporting);

        for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {

            $reporters[] = User::find($arr[$i]);

        }
        foreach ($reporters as $reporter) {
            //just for demo purpose
            echo $reporter->name . ' ';
        }
    }
}
```

Code could benefit from some serious refactoring but you get the idea.